# React js way to handle visibility=hidden

Tags: reactjs, visibility

I want to show or hide an element on the page, but still have it take up space when hidden so the layout doesn't shift, how do I do something like this?

```
abc: {
    visibility: 'visible',
  },
  xyz: {
    visibility: 'hidden',
  }
```

```
<div className={logoErrorMsg !== '' ? classes.abc : classes.xyz}>
              {logoErrorMsg !== ''  &&
                <Error
                  error={logoErrorMsg}
                />
             }
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you defined *logoErrorMsg* as a component state?

Comment: yes it is defined in state.

Comment: Instead of visibility, use opacity and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
{logoErrorMsg !== '' && (<div>
<Error
  error={logoErrorMsg}
/>
</div>)}
```